# Triggering a deployment using azure devops node api

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-node-sdk

How can I trigger a deployment using the azure devops node API? I do it manually as follows:

1. Go to the release page
2. Click on the latest release
3. Choose the env I want to deploy to (listed in the release stages)
4. Click deploy

I am able to get the release programmatically as follows:

```
const releaseApi: ra.IReleaseApi = await connection.getReleaseApi();

const releases: Release[] = await releaseApi.getReleases("b32aa71e-8ed2-41b2-9d77-5bc261222004", 34609, undefined);
```

What do I do next? I tried playing around with the `releaseDefinition` and the `releaseApi.updateRelease()` API unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to call request release with releaseStartMetadata object and Poject ID or project name
This would be equivalent to the rest call - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

```
let requestedRelease: ReleaseStartMetadata = { 
    definitionId: this.releaseConfiguration.pipelineId, // Sets definition Id to create a release.
    description: this.releaseConfiguration.description, // Sets description to create a release.
    isDraft: false, // Sets 'true' to create release in draft mode, 'false' otherwise.
    manualEnvironments: new Array<string>(), // Sets list of environments to manual as condition.
    properties: {},
    reason:  ReleaseReason.ContinuousIntegration, // Sets reason to create a release.
    //artifacts: releaseArtifacts // Sets list of artifact to create a release.
    // environmentsMetadata?: ReleaseStartEnvironmentMetadata[]; // Sets list of environments meta data.
    // variables?: { [key: string]: ConfigurationVariableValue; }; // Sets list of release variables to be overridden at deployment time.
};

console.log("Requesting release");
let curRelease = await releaseApi.createRelease(requestedRelease, this.releaseConfiguration.projectId);
if (release != null) {
    log.LogPipelineTriggered(pipelineName, projectName);
    log.LogPipelineTriggerOutput(release);
    if (release != null && release._links != null) {
        log.LogOutputUrl(release._links.web.href);
    }
}
```